# Running a build task to start a process and do not wait

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

How can I run a build pipeline task to start a process (in this case the Java process with Selenium grid) and continue the build pipeline?  I tried a number of different techniques with PowerShell (start-process, start-job) and command line but the build definition did not proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your issue. I build to powershell scripts in the same directory. `Scrip1.ps1` and `Scrip2.ps1`.

### `Scrip1.ps1`

```
Write-Host "Run Script2" -ForegroundColor Yellow
"TestFile" | Out-File "temp.txt"
Start-Process powershell ".\Script2.ps1" -WindowStyle Hidden
Write-Host "Run Script1 finished" -ForegroundColor Green
```

---

### `Scrip2.ps1`

```
Write-Host "Run Script2" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Start-Sleep -s 10
Remove-Item -Path "temp.txt" -Force
Write-Host "Run Script2 finished"
```

you will see that `Script1.ps1` finished long before `temp.txt` get deleted.

---

**Related to your Buildpipeline:**

**`Script1.ps1`** is your Task inside the buildpipeline (inlnie or as file)

**`Script2.ps1`** is your background process or the caller of the process your want to start (start your java process here)

Hope this solve the problem.